# How to config Google json key file as Spring core Resource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I'm developing a Spring boot application in Java 8. I'm trying to get the Google credential json file as spring core Resource object but it is not working. I have debug and see that **the serviceAccountKey was null because @Value("${google.service.account.key}") only load the path not the file**. Can somebody please show me how to handle this? I really don't know how to directly load the json key file.

Here are the code:

**GoogleDriveServiceImpl** **classs**

```
@Service
public class GoogleDriveServiceImpl implements GoogleDriveService {
    @Value("${google.service.account.key}")
    private Resource serviceAccountKey;

private Drive createDrive() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountKey.getInputStream())
            .createScoped(DriveScopes.all()));
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    return new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, requestInitializer)
            .setApplicationName("external").build();
    }
}
```

**Application.properties file**

```
google.service.account.key=H:\\document\\googleKey\\***********.json
server.port=8867
```

Comment: I would check the java client library to see if it even supports that https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client

Comment: @DaImTo I think the problem properly about how to load a JSON file as spring core Resource object, not related to google-api-java-clent.

Comment: Actually it is becouse as far as i can see the library wants you to send the path to the directory it does not accept a resource object, hence my saying i dont think its supported. and you should check the libary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I have found a way to load JSON key file as spring core Resource object: Instead of use direct path, I'm using the **classpath** preflix in @Value and **move the JSON key file into resource folder**.

Here are the code:

**GoogleDriveServiceImpl classs**

```
@Service
public class GoogleDriveServiceImpl implements GoogleDriveService {

    // Move the JSON key file into resource/google
    @Value("classpath:google/********.json")
    private Resource serviceAccountKey;

private Drive createDrive() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountKey.getInputStream())
            .createScoped(DriveScopes.all()));
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    return new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, requestInitializer)
            .setApplicationName("external").build();
    }
}
```